# How to set title of a xhtml panel when it is closed

Tags: primefaces, xhtml

I use this code:

```
<p:panel header="Advanced User Data" toggleable="true" toggleOrientation="horizontal" collapsed="true">
    some other stuff...
</p:panel>
```

Is there an attribute with which I can set the title when th panel is closed like this:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0jZW.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no attribute like this AFAIK. You could bind the value of `collapsed` attribute to a managed bean and add an AJAX listener on `toggle` event:

```
<p:panel header="Advanced User Data" toggleable="true"
    toggleOrientation="horizontal" collapsed="#{myBean.booleanVal}" style="display: inline-block;">
    <p:ajax event="toggle" process="@this" update="pnlAlternativeTitle" />
</p:panel>
<h:panelGroup id="pnlAlternativeTitle">
    <h:outputText rendered="#{myBean.booleanVal}"
        value="Alternative title" />
</h:panelGroup>
```